# Replace third word in double quotes from file

Tags: sed, rhel, perl, json

This is the `json` file that we want to edit

*Example 1*

```
{
  "topics": [{"topic": "hfgt_kejd_tdsfd”}],
  "version": 1
}
```

*Example 2*

```
{
  "topics": [{"topic": "hfgt_kj_fsrfdfd”}],
  "version": 1
}
```

We want to replace the third word in the line `topics` with other word ( by sed or perl one liner )

regarding to *example 1* , Expected results when we want to replace `hfgt_kejd_tdsfd` with `test_1`

```
{
  "topics": [{"topic": "test_1”}],
  "version": 1
}
```

*example 3*

```
more /tmp/file.json

{
  "topics": [{"topic": "TOPIC_GGGG”}],
  "version": 1
}


# sed  's/\(topic\": "\)[a-z_]*/\1test_1/'  /tmp/file.json

{
  "topics": [{"topic": "test_1TOPIC_GGGG”}],
  "version": 1
}
```

Comment: Your closing quote after the topic name is `”` (U+201D, `RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`) instead of a json quote (`"`, U+0022, `QUOTATION MARK`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `jq`:

```
$ jq '.topics[0].topic |= "test_1"' file.json
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "topic": "test_1"
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

This reads the JSON document and modifies the value of the `topic` entry of the first element of the array `topics` to the string `test_1`.

If you have your value in a variable (encoded in UTF-8):

```
$ val='Some value with "double quotes"'
$ jq --arg string "$val"  '.topics[0].topic |= $string' file.json
{
  "topics": [
    {
      "topic": "Some value with \"double quotes\""
    }
  ],
  "version": 1
}
```

---

Using Perl:

```
$ perl -MJSON -0777 -e '$h=decode_json(<>); $h->{topics}[0]{topic}="test_1"; print encode_json($h), "\n"' file.json
{"topics":[{"topic":"test_1"}],"version":1}
```

With a variable:

```
$ val='Some value with "double quotes"'
$ STRING=$val perl -MJSON -0777 -e '$string = $ENV{STRING}; utf8::decode $string; $h=decode_json(<>); $h->{topics}[0]{topic}=$string; print encode_json($h), "\n"' file.json
{"topics":[{"topic":"Some value with \"double quotes\""}],"version":1}
```

Both of these uses the Perl `JSON` module to decode the JSON document, change the value that needs changing, and then output the re-encoded data structure. The error handling is left as an exercise.

For the second piece of code, the value to be inserted is passed as an environment variable, `STRING`, into the Perl code.  This is due to reading the JSON document from file in "slurp" mode with `-0777`.

Comment: sorry for this note , but the quastion is about to use sed/perl one liner , I prefer to user sed/perl because this is very simple json and no need jq

Comment: @yael If it simple or not depends on the data that you'd want to insert. With `sed`, you would need to do the JSON encoding of your string yourself. I will add a Perl variation too (just need to test it first).

Comment: unfathomably , I not have the module as -  Can't locate JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains:  , maybe sed , is better +1 for your effort )

Comment: @yael On Ubuntu, it's in the `libjson-perl` package.

Comment: I have RHEL - 7.3

Comment: perl -v

This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 29 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: @yael The package is called `perl-JSON` on RedHat, but seriously, `jq` is as lightweight as `sed` (and Perl is _many times heavier_) and provides you with specialised JSON capabilities that `sed` would not be able to match. I wouldn't blink an eye to call `jq` just for JSON-encoding a string, if I needed to, because I know I don't have to care what's in the string. In your case, using `jq`, you would not have to care about the layout of the document (single line, or multiple lines, with varying line order). You're trading safety and convenience for perceived efficiency, if even that.

Comment: regarding to perl-JSON ( as you know we have rhel 7.x ) can you add the right perl syntax also for rhel 7.x?

Comment: @yael The Perl syntax is correct for Perl 5.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of matching `[A-Za-z_]` (which by the way matches a lot more than the English letters and underscore in most locales), use `[^"]` for *any character other than `"`* (by the way, the sample in your question has a `”` (U+201D, `RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK`) instead of a json quote (`"`, U+0022, `QUOTATION MARK`) as the closing quote after the topic name, I'll assume that's not the case in your original files as that would make it invalid json):

```
sed 's/\("topic": "\)[^"]*/\1test_1/' < file.json
```

(note that it's your responsibility to make sure the topic name replacement is properly JSON-encoded: UTF-8 charset, control characters encoded (like `\n` for newline), and `"` encoded as `\"`).

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i 's/\(topic\": "\)[A-Za-z_]*/\1test_1/' file.json
```

Comment: I test it , but its just add the test_1 before TOPIC_GGGG ( when topic name - TOPIC_GGGG  )

Comment: you can see example 3 in my question

Comment: @yael You could venture to change the regular expression they're showing. It currently expects a text consisting of characters `a-z` and `_` only. Remember to properly escape (or encode) any characters that needs to be escaped in JSON before inserting your new data.

Comment: As @Kusalananda noted, was trivial to add A-Z.  My answer updated so it now meets the recently added test cases in the question.